# How to translate files in a specific folder structure in .NET CORE 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core

Currently i have the following structure in my project:

[image]

The classes in the folder "database/entities" have some data annotations like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Es muss ein Titel eingegeben werden.")]
```

The problem is, that the translation doesn't work. In any case the german message is shown.

In other folders like in the "Models" Folder it works. Whats the problem there?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use **Istringlocalizer** or in other word resources file for supporting multilanguage items and it is better to use shared object instead of writting a message in static way

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Could you please explain it in more detail? My problem is that only the classes which are also used by the entity framework could not be translated.